# In Drupal 7 Commerce 1.x - is there a way to include the price into the dropdown product select box?

Tags: 7, commerce

Currently the price is outside of the select box on product display's. Is there a way to include the price in the select box itself?

**Example:**

**$5 - Basic Repair - Scratched Disc Recovery**

instead of whats below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the price in the product title itself in same way which you want to show in select box.

There are other way, in that you will have fetch the product id of the product reference field in `template.php` & load full product to get price. Then prepare title again at theme lavel..

For better understanding of what I am talking about, you can see my [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77555/how-to-replace-the-title-of-one-single-page-with-a-taxonomy-term/77565#77565) for a question here, where I have explained how to prepare title of node again which include taxonomy. You also have to do something similar like that..

But I will suggest you to follow the first solution of mine means - Include price with title of the product.